# How to replay the whole set of audios

Tags: jquery, html, audio

The following code plays the three audios automatically after the page loads after a delay of sometime between two audios. But I want to create a button "Replay" that repeats the above explained action automatically!

```
<audio id="my_audio" >
              <source src="bark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            <audio id="my_audio2">
              <source src="roar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <audio id="my_audio3">
              <source src="hoot.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#my_audio").get(0).play();

            $("#my_audio").bind("ended", function(){ 
                setTimeout(function() { $("#my_audio2").get(0).play(); },2000);

                $("#my_audio2").bind("ended", function(){ 
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#my_audio3").get(0).play(); },2000);                 
            });    
            });    
    });    

    </script>
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     RePlay();
     $("button").on("click",function(){ RePlay();}):
   });

   function RePlay(){
     $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
     $("#my_audio").bind("ended", function(){ 
        setTimeout(function() { $("#my_audio2").get(0).play(); },2000);
      $("#my_audio2").bind("ended", function(){ 
        setTimeout(function() { $("#my_audio3").get(0).play(); },2000);
      });
    });
  }
```